# Rcpp with embedded R code, show no output of R code

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a `cpp` file that defines `c++` and `R` functions, which are sourced into `R` using `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`.

When I source the file, the R code is (partially) printed as well, even when I specify `showOutput = FALSE` (I guess it only applies to `cpp` code?!).

The question now is: how can I suppress the partial R output without using `capture.output()` or similar tricks.

### MWE

in `tester.cpp`

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector timesTwo(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
  return x * 2;
}
/*** R
foo <- function(x) timesTwo(x)
*/
```

When sourcing the file, I see the following:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("tester.cpp", showOutput = FALSE)
#> foo <- function(x) timesTwo(x)
```

Even shorter MWE

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code='
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector timesTwo(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
  return x * 2;
}
/*** R
foo <- function(x) timesTwo(x)
*/
')
```

Comment: Any R code you have in your C++ code sourceCpp is [run with source(echo = TRUE)](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/e0353c7e1eb57f54e01a2ef0319d74b78e476f18/R/Attributes.R#L217). if you don't want that to happen, then I suggest you take the R code out of the C++ file and just move it to where you are calling `sourceCpp` or [file an issue](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues) to request a new feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this question be rooted in a misunderstanding of what `showOutput` is for?

Looking at `help(sourceCpp)` we see

> `showOutput: ‘TRUE’ to print ‘R CMD SHLIB’ output to the console.`

that it affects *the actual compilation step* and has nothing to do with any R code added as optional bit to also run if present.

The following example should make this clear (and reveal a few of `CXX` and other settings):

```
> cppFunction("int doubleMe(int i) { return i+i; }", showOutput=TRUE)
/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_10.so' 'file99f11710553a7.cpp' 
ccache g++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/tmp/RtmpC7dZ23/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.5.4"    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic  -c file99f11710553a7.cpp -o file99f11710553a7.o
ccache g++ -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o sourceCpp_10.so file99f11710553a7.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
>
> cppFunction("int trippleMe(int i) { return i+i+i; }", showOutput=FALSE)
>
```

Now, suppressing output of *R* code is a different topic and orthogonal to whether such code contains element made via `Rcpp` or not.

And lastly @MrFlick is spot on that if you don't want R code sourced as part of a `sourceCpp()` call ... then just don't include such code!  Or just break the regexp `/*** R`.

Comment: That is definitely the case that I misunderstood `showOutput`... Would you be interested in a PR to have `showROutput` or similar in `Rcpp`? Or is this too much of an edge-case?

Comment: Well as we say at GH [in the files that pops up](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md), we _much_ prefer issue discussion first. This is JJ's baby so I would want his buyout first.  We could add an option but then ... didn't you demonstrate convincingly that nobody looks at options or help files?  ;-)  Kidding aside it's both "could do" and "pretty marginal". My inclination would be to not rock the boat over this.

Comment: Oh, and I win typo of the day with last comment:  `s/buyout/buy-in/`.  Really should not type when being absent-minded.  Or start to proof-read.  But why start now...

Comment: Sounds a lot better to have JJ's buy-in regarding the issue than his buyout of Rcpp(?!) :)